# вывести ошибку валидации над полем C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, валидация, asp, атрибуты

```
[Desc]
    public class Product
    {
        public enum Category { Toy, Technique, Clothes, Transport}

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Category Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class DescAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public DescAttribute()
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Description text is not valid";
        }
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            Product p = value as Product;

            return p is null ||
                (p.Description.StartsWith(p.Name) && p.Description != p.Name && p.Description.Length > 2);
        }
    }
```

В моём случае если валидация не успешна ошибка выводится вверху страницы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так чтобы эта ошибка валидация выводилась около поля Description ?

Comment: Можно надпись оставить как есть, а у неверно заполненного поля нарисовать красный бортик. Вы пробовали атрибут над свойствами ставить а не над классом?

Comment: у вас вопрос про представлению - покажите код представления. Есть же всякие расширения типа `Html.Va;lidationMessageFor(model=>model.Props)`

Comment: @aepot пробовал над свойством Description, но потом не понял как достучаться до поля Name мне в return'е

Comment: А зачем? Если вы валидируете Name, только его и проверяйте. По атрибуту над каждым свойством. Поизучайтп валидацию подробнее. Сдается мне, что не стоит заводить кастомные атрибуты на каждое свойство.

Comment: @aepot условие такое чтобы Description начинался на Name

Comment: Интересное требование, а зачем ему начинаться на Name? Просто интересно. Смысл заставлять юзера вводить одно и то же дважды? Это же не пароль.

Comment: @aepot типичные требования к задачкам на курсах))

Comment: А как валидируют в форме авторизации, корректно ли заполнено повторение пароля? В функции задействовано 2 свойства. Я бы где-то там решение искал, оно должно быть популярным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Remote(action: "VerifyDescription", controller: "Products", AdditionalFields = nameof(Name))]
        public string Description { get; set; }
```

в Контроллере :

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
        public IActionResult VerifyDescription(string Description, string Name)
        {
            if (Description.Equals(Name) || !Description.StartsWith(Name))
            {
                return Json("Description text is not valid.");
            }

            return Json(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно переопределить `protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)`

В атрибуте для класса:

```
protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    Product p = value as Product;
    if (p is null || (p.Description.StartsWith(p.Name) && p.Description != p.Name && p.Description.Length > 2))
        return null;
    else
        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage, new string[] { nameof(p.Description) });
}
```

Если хотите написать атрибут для свойства, вы можете получить весь объект в `validationContext.ObjectInstance` чтоб потом обратиться к `Name` :

```
protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var product = validationContext.ObjectInstance as Product;
    if (product is null)
        return null;

    var desc = value.ToString();

    if (desc.StartsWith(product.Name) && desc != product.Name && desc.Length > 2)
        return null;
    else
        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
}
```

И не забудьте в представлении добавить `<span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>` чтоб было куда выводить текст валидации.